# Shiprocket API - test environment, test shipment

Tags: php, integration, development-environment, shiprocket

For my client I am integrating Shiprocket services with his system.

I rely on the documentation ([ApiDocs](https://apidocs.shiprocket.in/)) and the Postman collection ([Postman Collection](https://www.postman.com/shiprocketdev/workspace/shiprocket-dev-s-public-workspace/collection/8407119-f5af337c-69fc-49c7-8418-e2f6ee461674)).

The main problem for me is the lack of a test environment (if I'm wrong, and there is one, please let me know).

I have access to my client's account.
I need to know how to send a parcel via a selected courier.
The shipping order itself is not a big problem, but it involves costs, even in the case of test shipments.
Is there any way to fully integrate this API without incurring operational costs during testing?

I am looking for a person who has experience in working with this API and is able to help me implement the appropriate methods.